# Indian-Chinese unmarried couple got pregnant. How to get Chinese citizenship for the baby?

Tags: visa, china

I'm Indian and my girlfriend is Chinese. She is 6 months pregnant. We both are in India. We don't have a marriage certificate yet because we failed to provide all the required documents to the authorities.

We are flying to China this week. How to get citizenship for the baby?

Comment: Since you are flying to China this week, does that mean she will give birth in China?

Comment: Yes. She will give birth in China. but in china unmarried person cannot have baby.

Answer (score 1):

According to Article 4 of the PRC Nationality Law, a child born in China to at least one Chinese citizen parent is automatically a Chinese citizen at birth, with no other conditions.

What do you mean when you say "in china unmarried person cannot have baby"? I am not familiar with the situation with children born out of wedlock in China, but I don't think they physically prevent people from giving birth. Perhaps you mean that the child cannot be added to hukou or cannot get a travel document? or that the there may be a penalty?

Comment: Second this--I know of an out-of-wedlock birth in China.

Comment: A big penalty, or cannot be added to hukou.

Comment: Don't think it would be a problem nowadays. There are tons of out-of-wedlock births currently. That notion was very old.